# how do I add a class for only one element on click?

Tags: vue.js

There are several blocks, when you click on the button, the "show" class appears, how do I make sure that this class is only for the block that was clicked on, and does not appear at all?

```js
export default {
    data() {
    return {
      show: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {

  },
  methods: {
    openItem() {
      this.show = !this.show;
    },
  },
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
}

.box-show {
  display: none
}

.item.show .box-show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <div class="box">
    <div class="item" :class="{show: show}">
      <button class="btn-click" @click="openItem">click</button>
      <div class="box-show">contetn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" :class="{show: show}">
      <button class="btn-click" @click="openItem">click</button>
      <div class="box-show">contetn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" :class="{show: show}">
      <button class="btn-click" @click="openItem">click</button>
      <div class="box-show">contetn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" :class="{show: show}">
      <button class="btn-click" @click="openItem">click</button>
      <div class="box-show">contetn</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

That is, just add a class to one element, not to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use v-for and an array to achieve the desired effect

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .box {
    display: flex;
    gap: 12px;
  }

  .box-show {
    display: none;
  }

  .item.show .box-show {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<div id="app">
  <div class="box">
    <div
      class="item"
      v-for="(item, i) in items"
      :key="i"
      :class="{show: item.show}"
    >
      <button class="btn-click" @click="openItem(i)">{{item.btnName}}</button>
      <div class="box-show">{{item.content}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const { createApp } = Vue

  const app = createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        items: [
          {
            btnName: 'click',
            content: 'content',
            show: false,
          },
          {
            btnName: 'click',
            content: 'content',
            show: false,
          },
          {
            btnName: 'click',
            content: 'content',
            show: false,
          },
          {
            btnName: 'click',
            content: 'content',
            show: false,
          },
        ],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      openItem(index) {
        this.items[index].show = !this.items[index].show
      },
    },
  })

  app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use component: make `div class="item"` to a `Item.vue` component.

Item.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="item" :class="{show: show}">
    <button class="btn-click" @click="openItem">click</button>
    <div class="box-show">contetn</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openItem() {
      this.show = !this.show;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.box-show {
  display: none
}

.item.show .box-show {
  display: block
}
</style>
```

App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="box">
    <Item />
    <Item />
    <Item />
    <Item />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Item from './Item.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Item,
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.box {
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
}
</style>
```

You can test it at https://playcode.io/1795466